# Custom alert box dialog Fragment error

Tags: android

By pressing delete button on Activity A. The following custom fragment opens. So if I press Ok button on the custom alertbox how to make it run deleteRecord() function which is in activity A. My code for custom alert box is:

```
public class CustomAlertBoxFragment extends DialogFragmentBase implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public TextView messageTextView;
    public Boolean proceed;
    public String messages;
    private MyFragment mListener;

    interface MyFragment {
        public void removeAllButton_onClick();
    }

    public CustomAlertBoxFragment(Activity a,Boolean proceed, String message) {
        this.messages = message;
        this.proceed = proceed;
        this.c = a;
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) c.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(25);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        getActivity().setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
        mListener = (MyFragment)activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_custom_alertbox, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        v.findViewById(R.id.okButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.closeButton).setOnClickListener(this);
        messageTextView.setText(messages);

        getActivity().setTheme(R.style.iconDialogTheme);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.okButton:
                mListener.removeAllButton_onClick();
                break;
            case R.id.closeButton:
                dismiss();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CustomAlertBoxFragment declare an interface:

```
interface AlertBoxListener {
      public void onDeleteRecord();
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity implements CustomAlertBoxFragment.AlertBoxListener {
 ....

   public void onDeleteRecord() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IT WORKS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

Now store the reference in the dialog:

```
public class CustomAlertBoxFragment ... {

    private AlertBoxListener mListener; 


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
         ....
         mListener = (AlertBoxListener)activity;
    }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.okButton:
            mListener.onDeleteRecord();
            break;
         ....
   }
```

And just call the onDeleteRecord when needed - it will run in your activity

Comment: didnt work for me. I tried to call ondeleterecord on case R.id.okbutton

Comment: What exactly didn't work? That's the correct solution, if you call the onDeleteRecord in the fragment, it will run that method in your activity. From there you can do whatever you need.

Comment: it showing me error " cannot reslove methon 'ondeleterecord()'  "

Comment: You must implement the interface in your activity, as I mentioned. See the edited answer

Comment: I have edit my question code. can you see if i did anything wrong than you told?

Comment: It looks good, if you also implemented the interface in the activity, it will work

Comment: just see my edited post where I added a piece of code you need to add to your DashboardActivity

Answer (score -1):

1. AFAIK, Activities, by default, get all onClick events for buttons present in the fragments attached to it. So you can simply have that onClick method in your MainActivity and process your calculations. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong here.
2. OR, Use an interface. ([Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html))
3. Lastly, the worst method of all, you can store the activity instance by overriding `onAttach()` and simply call the method in your Activity A.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       ActivityA activityA = ((ActivityA ) activity);
   }
   ```

and wherever you require it:

```
    activityA.yourMethodHere(someRandomParam);
```

Comment: Activities don't handle any events in fragments. Also, casting activity and directly calling its methods is really bad in case you would reuse the fragment in any other activity

Comment: srbyk1990, an interface is guaranteed to work. That's the best way. And Anton, yeah that's right. It's good only when you do not intend to re-use the DialogFragment.